# What does the "1" argument define in this line of text?

Tags: python, pygame

score.Blit = self.score.Font.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))

in the above line of code, I understand that the . . . '.score'- gets the score for the previously identified "self", .Font.render- draws the score in the specific font on the screen identified as the (string of self.score), and the (255, 255, 255)- identifies the color of the font to be white. What I cannot figure out is what the "1" id identifying? I have changed this # to a 0, to 500, to 200 and it does not appear to change anything on the screen. I have included the block of code that this comes from for clarification in case it is needed for further explanation.

```
    def scoring(self):
            scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
            screen.blit(scoreBlit, (SCR_HEI+96, 16))
            if self.score == 10:
                    print ("Player 2 wins!")
                    exit()
```

This is python and runs in pygame

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render

Answer (score 0):

See [`render()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render). This argument can be either `True` or `False` and specifies whether the text will be rendered with ore without [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing).

Compare text rendering with and without anti-aliasing:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok this makes sense, I guess with the text I am using it is not evident so that is why I am not seeing the change. Thank you for the explination.

Comment: @marlo You will only see a change when you switch to 0.